# Gatttool disconnection in bluez 5.3+ causes very high cpu usage (Linux bluetooth)

Tags: linux, android-bluetooth, bluez

I am using bluez 5.37 backported to linux 2.6 due to project restrictions on a custom device. I have noticed gatttool causes a very high cpu usage on disconnection. This is very easy to replicate. Use gatttool in interactive mode to connect to any BLE device and then disconnect. CPU usage is fine till you give the disconnect command. Observe CPU usage, gatttool will cross 70-80%. I can also replicate this on Ubuntu LTS. Has anyone had a go at fixing this?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you please add the code you are using? If you are using no code and this is an ubuntu inbuilt feature better ask at askubunutu.com Thanks!

Comment: It is more a bluez question. Actually there is no code, it is just a tool. So to scan a BLE device you could use a number of methods. 
For e.g. hcitool lescan
After the device is found, you can copy it's MAC address and use the command 
gatttool -b <mac_addr> -I
Then type connect.
Then type disconnect.
Observe 'top' at all time.

Comment: then please either ask at a *bluez*-specific platform or at http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'bluez-specific platform'?

Comment: a online community/product platform especially for whatever *bluez* is. i dont know it by myself but it is definitely going way too deep for stack overflow. for the beginning just try askubuntu, please.

Comment: I have seen some posts on bluez, and that's the reason I took a shot. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess I found what is wrong. Gatttool uses glib main event loop and so io channels are attached as sources to the default main context (read glib docs for more clarification). As an example in  'bluez/attrib/interactive.c'  in function cmd_connect 'g_io_add_watch(iochannel, G_IO_HUP, channel_watcher, NULL)' is done. This function will return a gsource which has to be removed from watch once io channel is lost or deleted. In absence of this, glib will keep waiting on this io channel (fd) and cause EINVAL as return code. (My knowledge is patchy but I guess that's what happens). So when disconnecting the device this watch needs to be removed.
I do it in following way - define a new global  - 
`guint gsrc;`
Change the line in cmd_connect to
`gsrc = g_io_add_watch(iochannel, G_IO_HUP, channel_watcher, NULL);` 
After disconnection, in disconnect_io function before return -                   `g_source_remove(gsrc);`
This fixes gatttool cpu usage  bug in interactive mode.

Comment: Please do not post link only answers. Especially links which require a login (which yours does). Put the contents into the answer itself.

Comment: I don't think it needs login.I did check. But I will edit the answer